# Bash code to convert UTM x/y to lat/long Decimal Degrees

Tags: bash, grid, latitude-longitude, utm, wgs84

I was wondering if there is a bash code (or maybe other language, e.g. Python, Perl) to convert UTM x/y coordinates to lat/long coordinates? A code that can convert multiple coordinates at a time. I'm working in UTM zone 29N, using WGS84 datum.

Example of UTM x/y coordinates:

```
616928  6877084
621751  6877314
614317  6871645
588506  6883397
570571  6886266
```

Desired output in Decimal Degrees:

```
62.008000   -6.766680087
62.008542   -6.674491852
61.960009   -6.819994839
62.072357   -7.306064871
62.101883   -7.648054115
```

Comment: You should probably explain what the conversion algorithm is. People like me, who do not want to search what UTM coordinates are, but who maybe know how to implement the algorithm could answer your question.

Comment: In case you are still wondering what the conversion algorithm is: http://www.uwgb.edu/dutchs/usefuldata/utmformulas.htm

Comment: @DrGranit - Thank you. However, I actually found this site some time ago, but forgot to report back here. Steven Dutch has helped us out on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a single coordinate

```
echo 616928  6877084  | gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:25829 -t_srs epsg:4326
```

To convert a set of coordinates like your example:

```
616928  6877084
621751  6877314
614317  6871645
588506  6883397
570571  6886266
```

Save them to coords.txt and run:

```
cat coords.txt | gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:25829 -t_srs epsg:4326
```